# Django: Calculate difference between fields on rows from same model

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a model which represents a duration from the start of a run in a sport:

```py
class Time(models.Model):
    # A participator of a race
    bib = models.ForeignKey(Bib, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # A timing point. Could be one at 0km, 5km and at the goal
    timing_point = models.ForeignKey(TimingPoint, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # The duration from start
    time = models.FloatField()
```

I want to calculate the duration between two timing points for each bib. The result should be a QuerySet with one row for each bib. I assume it would be most efficient if the data fetching and the duration calculation could be accomplished in one database query. Can this be done and how?

To clarify the goal, this is how I do it now (exception handling removed):

```py
    times = []
    for bib in bibs:       
        from_time = Time.objects.get(timing_point=from_point, bib=bib)        
        to_time = Time.objects.get(timing_point=to_point, bib=bib)
        times.append({'bib': bib, 'time': to_time.time - from_time.time, })
```

I want to avoid hitting the database this many times and I would prefer if the result could be a QuerySet since I want to be able do additional stuff like ordering.

Comment: What Django version are you using?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I am using Django 2.2. I will try your suggested solution soon but it looks very promising. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [django-2.0](/questions/tagged/django-2.0) and higher, we can use `.annotate(..)` with an aggregate like `Min`, and a `filter=...` condition on that aggregate, like:

```
from django.db.models import F, Min, Q

t2=Min('time__time', filter=Q(time__timing_point=to_point))
t1=Min('time__time', filter=Q(time__timing_point=from_point))

Bib.objects.annotate(dtime=t2-t1)
```

We first introduce two variables:

1. `t2` will contain the smallest `time` for a *related* `Time` object with `timing_point` the `to_point` (likely there is only one); and
2. `t1` will contain the smallest `time` for a *related* `Time` object with `timing_point` the `from_point`.

We then make an annotation `dtime` with the difference between `t2` and `t1`.

Since this is still part of the `QuerySet`, we can even order the `Bib`s on the `dtime`, etc.

Django will convert this to a query that looks like:

```
SELECT bib.*,
       (MIN(CASE WHEN time.timing_point_id = 2 THEN time.time ELSE NULL END) -
        MIN(CASE WHEN time.timing_point_id = 1 THEN time.time ELSE NULL END)) AS dtime
FROM bib
LEFT OUTER JOIN time ON bib.id = time.bib_id GROUP BY bib.id
```

With `2` and `1` in reality the primary keys of `to_point` and `from_point` respectively.

It might improve the efficiency of the query a bit further if you filter on the `Timing` model as well:

```
from django.db.models import F, Min, Q

t2=Min('time__time', filter=Q(time__timing_point=to_point))
t1=Min('time__time', filter=Q(time__timing_point=from_point))

Bib.objects.filter(
    time__timing_point__in=[from_point, to_point]
).annotate(dtime=t2-t1)
```

this will result in a query that looks like:

```
SELECT bib.*,
       (MIN(CASE WHEN time.timing_point_id = 2 THEN time.time ELSE NULL END) -
        MIN(CASE WHEN time.timing_point_id = 2 THEN time.time ELSE NULL END)) AS dtime
FROM bib LEFT OUTER JOIN time ON bib.id = time.bib_id
WHERE time.timing_point_id IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY bib.id
```

Comment: Now _that_ is a solid answer.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Tested and it works very well. Thank you!